# Azure Hosted EchoBOT channelised to view in Teams but nothing is visible in Teams

Tags: azure, chatbot, microsoft-teams

I am new to Azure services and trying to do an exercise  of creating EchoBOt in the Azure Cloud services using my own subscription. After creating the ChatBOT in the Azure portal and channelized to import it in the Teams app, I tried opening the Teams but I dont see any chatbot listed in the left hand side. In the Azure portal, I can see in the 'Connect to Channel' page , both the 'Webchat' and 'Microsoft Teams' in running status. Please help what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

To access your EchoBOt in teams you need to upload your manifest in Teams Appstudio Or else Create a new app in Teams Appstudio with your existing AppId. Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/deploy-and-publish/apps-upload) for more info.